# How to resize/lengthen/truncate a file and leave more room at the beginning?

Tags: c++, c, file, file-io, truncate

One of the side uses of `ftruncate()` is that we can resize a file by just sticking zeros onto the end of the file assuming that you request a new file size larger than the original.  This seems like a low cost solution to resizing a file since it modifies the file descriptor, etc.  This is a great solution when we want the newly created region to exist at the end of the file (similar to how `realloc()` gives you the new space after your original content).

But what about the beginning!  What if I want to resize the file but get my new space at the beginning of the file?  I can't really believe that I have to simply copy all of the data into a later portion of the file (or do I?).  It would be a terribly time consuming operation!  Is there a better way?

Comment: Do you have any technical reasoning for believing such an operation would be useful and/or efficient?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think so, especially not in a an OS agnostic way.  You would be depending on the OS to allocate a disk block and prepending it to the list of blocks the file uses.  Blocks are of a fixed size, so even if there was a way your data would have to match the block size.